# For loop wait for completion of called method

Tags: java, android, file, audio-converter

I have a code which is checking a defined type of audio file in folder and calling converter to change its format. Now when first file is passed, converter is called and as file is in process of being conversion, for loop called converter again for second file. In this i felt earlier/later process is terminated and hence i m getting only file converted as output. Code is here. How can i  manage to get all files convereted.

```
public void convertAudio(View v) {


        final File pathanme = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sdcard/test");
        File files[] = pathanme.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.getName().endsWith(".mp4")) {
                String filename = f.getName().toLowerCase().toString();
                System.out.println(filename);

                File wavFile = new File(pathanme, filename);
                IConvertCallback callback = new IConvertCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(File convertedFile) {
                        Toast.makeText(NewMainActivity.this, "SUCCESS: " + convertedFile.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Exception error) {
                        Toast.makeText(NewMainActivity.this, "ERROR: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                };
                Toast.makeText(this, "Converting audio file..." + filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                AndroidAudioConverter.with(this)
                        .setFile(wavFile)
                        .setFormat(AudioFormat.MP3)
                        .setCallback(callback)
                        .convert();
            }
        }
```

If u see there is success message against conversion and i never got this under for loop whereas if i pass only one file, i got success message. pls advice.

Comment: Please contact library's author to support multiple files or do some semaphore(basic multithreinding sync concept) which would not allow `convert()` call without finishing previous job

Comment: People are so keen to downgrade question of beginner instead of supporting. i afraid to ask here now.

Comment: People are so lazy to ask before do some research ...

Comment: It's your perception, did you check my search log, time spent in studying or finding solution before asking. And I request then donot comment on silly question if you donot like them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class instance variable for an index and increment it as necessary, calling the `convert()` method recursively as necessary. It'd look something like this (Java is a little rusty, you may have to clean up syntax):

```
public class MyClass {

   private int fileIndex = 0;
   private File[] files;

   public void convertAudio(View v) {
     final File pathanme = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sdcard/test");
     this.files = pathanme.listFiles();
     fileIndex = 0;
     convertFile(files[fileIndex]);

  }

   private void convertFile(File f) {
      if (f.getName().endsWith(".mp4")) {
         String filename = f.getName().toLowerCase().toString();
         System.out.println(filename);

         File wavFile = new File(pathanme, filename);
         IConvertCallback callback = new IConvertCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(File convertedFile) {
               Toast.makeText(NewMainActivity.this, "SUCCESS: " + convertedFile.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               fileIndex++;
               if (this.files.size > fileIndex) {
                  convertFile(this.files[fileIndex];
               } else {
                  // we're done converting
               }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception error) {
               Toast.makeText(NewMainActivity.this, "ERROR: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               // cancel out or keep going, whatever
            }
         };

            Toast.makeText(this, "Converting audio file..." + filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            AndroidAudioConverter.with(this)
                    .setFile(wavFile)
                    .setFormat(AudioFormat.MP3)
                    .setCallback(callback)
                    .convert();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Logically it is working fine, only issue left is as converter take too much memory, so system start suspending threads.

Comment: Good to know. If you struggle with the memory issues, create a separate question with updated information and code. Good luck!